# Python Watch Folder - interrogating list for filesize

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to get the following code to watch a folder for changes and return the filename (preferably a full path) as a string once it's checked that the filesize hasn't increased recently, to stop the rest of my script inspecting incomplete files.
I'm having difficulty with sending my filesize timer function a filename because i'm collecting the detected files as a list.
If i'm barking up the wrong tree feel free to tell me, and thanks for any help!

Stewart

```
import os, time

def watch(path_to_watch):
    before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
    while watch_active == 1:
        time.sleep (10)
        after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
        added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
        removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
        if added:
            filesizechecker(added)
            return added
        if removed:
            print "Removed: ", ", ".join (removed)
        before = after

def filesizechecker(filepath):
# Checks filesize of input file and 
# returns 1 when file hasn't changed for 3 seconds
    fnow = open(filepath, "rb")
    fthen = 1
    while fnow != fthen:
        time.sleep(3)
        fthen = len(f.read())

watch_active = 1
watch("/home/stewart/Documents")
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the best way to test that a file isn't "in progress"? You could, for instance, process incomplete files in a temp directory and then `os.rename` (this being atomic) them into the main dir.

Comment: Oh, you should use `set` instead of `dict`; for one, it's the right way to do things -- but not only that, you could then do `added = after - before`! So do e.g. `before = set( os.listdir( ... ) )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and discovered the pyinotify library was much more suited to my needs.

Specifically the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` Event Code returns when an application (in my case, a file copy) closes a writable file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check how `lsof` works. It lists the open files. If the file you're watching (or want) isn't open it is also not probable that it is being changed.

You're on Linux so you can always check the /proc filesystem for information on processes and files.

I don't know the details, so it's upt o you weather this line of thinking is worth your time:)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, extraneon. But the files would very often be transfered over samba/nfs/afp from other machines and I have just tested lsof and ps aux and they didn't pick up the file copy I was making over samba.